# Regular expression does not accept # character in password

Tags: regex, passwords

Here is the regex:

```
("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\\d$@$!%*#?&]{8,50}")
```

Password must have minimum 8 and maximum 50 characters at least 1 Uppercase Alphabet, 1 Lowercase Alphabet, 1 Number and 1 Special Character.

But this expression does not accept # in password

Comment: I think you might be using Java. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

It works properly for me:

[image]

Could you post the way you implement it?

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression seems to work fine for me too:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[$@!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\\d$@!%*#?&]{8,50}");
    System.out.println(pat.matcher("#GRDiD1ddddddddd").matches());
    System.out.println(pat.matcher("GRDiD1ddddddddd!#").matches());
    System.out.println(pat.matcher("GRDiD1d#ddddddd!").matches());
    System.out.println(pat.matcher("GRDiD1d#dd#ddddd!").matches());
}
```

This prints out:

```
true
true
true
true
```

By the way, the regular expression contains redundant dollar characters and could be simplified to:

```
(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[$@!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\\d$@!%*#?&]{8,50}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[!-/])[!-z]{8,50}")
```